# MySQL Left Join returning unrelated records despite using IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql

The following query with left joins returns records that do not have a match on the final left join, i.e. the assessment column is null, though I have the query with `IS NOT NULL` .

How should the query be changed to get just the matching records?

Basically I want to return unit_outcome records GROUPED according to related assessments in the lookup table.

[DB Fiddle for LEFT JOIN](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w5c5JzGFeHi1DjSJy3EE5w/1) showing records with null for assessment

```
SELECT *
  FROM unit
  left JOIN unit_unit_outcome_lookup
    ON unit_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_fk = unit.unit_pk
  left JOIN unit_outcome
    ON unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk = unit_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_outcome_fk
  left JOIN unit_outcome_assessment_lookup
    ON unit_outcome_assessment_lookup.unit_outcome_fk = unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk IS NOT NULL
  left JOIN assessment
    ON assessment.assessment_pk = unit_outcome_assessment_lookup.assessment_fk IS NOT NULL
    AND unit.unit_pk ='1'
```

[DB Fiddle for INNER JOIN](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dHSdfigoSUuNT8Wh5T3fbF/1) with no null records - how to group unit_outcomes by assessment?

Comment: *ON assessment.assessment_pk = unit_outcome_assessment_lookup.assessment_fk IS NOT NULL* How do you think what operation is performed: `ON (assessment.assessment_pk = unit_outcome_assessment_lookup.assessment_fk) IS NOT NULL` or `ON assessment.assessment_pk = (unit_outcome_assessment_lookup.assessment_fk IS NOT NULL)`?

Comment: you need to add where condition, where you check something is not null

Comment: @Akina  To not return results that do not have a related assessment in the assessment table

Comment: o_O Use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT...

Comment: @Mangesh Auti  Can you show me in a fork of the fiddle?

Comment: @Akina, I tried an INNER JOIN, but I just get all records, based on the total number of unit_outcome records....a working fiddle would be useful.

Comment: @Akina, INNER JOIN does work better, with correct matches of records, but I get duplicate assessment records e.g. look at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dHSdfigoSUuNT8Wh5T3fbF/1     I was hoping the a JOIN (LEFT or INNER) would enable DISTINCT records for assessment.  Basically, I want to group unit_outcomes according to related assessments.

Comment: *I get duplicate assessment records* I do not see duplicates (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8efa9e2951928607e7bf4b804fc26819), the most last simplified query). PS. I move the fiddle to dbfiddle.uk because db-fiddle.com ;ags for me sometimes. PPS. Show desired result - add only the columns needed for to explain its logic to the last query, and remove excess columns for joining tables.

Comment: @Akina  Thanks for your help.  Is there a way to group the unit outcomes by assessment?  For example for assessment_pk 1 which has 3 outcomes (pks 1, 2 and 3), to have those grouped together as a comma seperated record?  Does this need another SO question?

Comment: I think I know how to fix your problem, but can you just explain in English what you want? And please change your table names to something very short, eg `tab1`, `tab2` etc; it’s much easier to read (the query is currently mostly noise due to excessively long table names), loses no information and makes the question more generic so it is useful to the general coding population.

Comment: @Bohemian, I want to group results so that for example, unit outcomes are grouped to assessment as a parent child relationship.  This could be grouping the unit outcomes by assessment to produce a comma seperated record like CONCAT that I can then, with PHP, convert commas to line breaks.    This could give me, in a table through PHP formatting, assessment on the left and unit outcomes to the right of the assessment

Comment: I would have thought that the context of the table names unit, unit_outcomes, assessment (e.g. academic context) with the 2 corresponding lookup tables might be more intuitive than using non-descriptive names for the tables...

Comment: *For example for assessment_pk 1 which has 3 outcomes (pks 1, 2 and 3)* Fiddle shows 2 records for `assessment_pk=1`... and no `pks` column at all. Please refer to fiddle data, not to abstract values. Check [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f6d17a2f31a822992dd36fb65eaf7c59) - does the last query gives the result which you need?

Comment: @Akina, yes I was looking for GROUP_CONCAT().  Though I am getting in my environment FUNCTION cm_md.ANY_VALUE does not exist  MySQL 5.1.73

Comment: *FUNCTION cm_md.ANY_VALUE does not exist MySQL 5.1.73* Replace with MAX(). It doesn't matter because of `unit.unit_pk ='1'` condition. Or remove this field from output list at all.

Comment: @Akina  Thanks again, do you want to put that into an answer?  I will also need unit_outcome.unit_outcome and assessment.assessment in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX((unit.unit_pk)) AS unit_pk,
       GROUP_CONCAT(unit_outcome.unit_outcome) unit_outcomes,
       MAX(assessment.assessment) assessment,
       GROUP_CONCAT(unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk) unit_outcome_pks, 
       assessment.assessment_pk
FROM unit
INNER JOIN unit_unit_outcome_lookup
    ON unit_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_fk = unit.unit_pk
INNER JOIN unit_outcome
    ON unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk = unit_unit_outcome_lookup.unit_outcome_fk
INNER JOIN unit_outcome_assessment_lookup
    ON unit_outcome_assessment_lookup.unit_outcome_fk = unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk
INNER JOIN assessment
    ON assessment.assessment_pk = unit_outcome_assessment_lookup.assessment_fk
    AND unit.unit_pk ='1'
GROUP BY assessment_pk;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8f40e22f735afbeec30758877590b971)

PS. Details can be found in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this one,

> unit_outcome_assessment_lookup.unit_outcome_fk = unit_outcome.unit_outcome_pk IS NOT NULL

If you want to select only what is existing on the other table use INNER JOIN or JOIN. Lets understand how join works: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp.

Also use ALIAS on tables to make the query easier to read.

```
SELECT *
  FROM unit u
  LEFT JOIN unit_unit_outcome_lookup uuol ON uuol.unit_fk = u.unit_pk
  LEFT JOIN unit_outcome uo ON uo.unit_outcome_pk = uuol.unit_outcome_fk
  JOIN unit_outcome_assessment_lookup uoal ON uoal.unit_outcome_fk = uo.unit_outcome_pk
  JOIN assessment a ON a.assessment_pk = uoal.assessment_fk
WHERE u.unit_pk ='1'
```